# How to use enums in Qt signals and slots

Tags: c++, qt, enums

I have some trouble with using `enum` types in signals. Basicly I have two classes, a state machine and a thread handling the state machine. When the state is changed I want to send a signal with the new state. I also want to represent the state using an `enum`. In my full blown code the state machine is implemented in a separate shared library, but the code below gives the exact same error.

When I run the code I get the following behaviour:

```
kotte@EMO-Ubuntu:sigenum $ ./sigenum 
Object::connect: No such slot MyThread::onNewState(state)
Test signal 
Test signal 
...
```

I have four files in my sample code: `statemachine.h`, `statemachine.cpp`, `main.h` and `main.cpp`. The main function simply starts the thread, the thread then creates an instance of the `StateMachine` and processes signals from the `StateMachine`. I am pretty new to Qt, so I was a bit puzzled when I realised that you have to enclose the enum with `Q_ENUMS` and register it with the type system. So It's fully possible that I've made some rookie mistake

The code below is a bit long, but I wanted it to be as similar to my real code as possible.

`statemachine.h` looks like:

```c
// statemachine.h
#ifndef _STATEMACHINE_H
#define _STATEMACHINE_H

#include <QtCore>

class StateMachine : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_ENUMS(state)

public:
    enum state {S0, S1, S2};

    void setState(state newState);

signals:
    void stateChanged(state newState);
    void testSignal(void);
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(StateMachine::state);

#endif
```

And it is implemented as:

```c
// statemachine.cpp
#include <QtCore>

#include "statemachine.h"

void StateMachine::setState(state newState)
{
    emit stateChanged(newState);
    emit testSignal();
}
```

The thread is defined as

```c
// main.h
#ifndef _MAIN_H
#define _MAIN_H

#include <QtCore>

#include "statemachine.h"

class MyThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    void run(void);

private slots:
    void onNewState(StateMachine::state);
    void onTestSignal(void);

private:
    StateMachine *myStateMachine;
};

#endif
```

And it is implemented as follows:

```c
// main.cpp
#include <QtCore>
#include <QApplication>

#include "statemachine.h"
#include "main.h"

void MyThread::run()
{
    myStateMachine = new StateMachine();

    qRegisterMetaType<StateMachine::state>("state");

    // This does not work
    connect(myStateMachine, SIGNAL(stateChanged(state)),
            this, SLOT(onNewState(state)));

    // But this does...
    connect(myStateMachine, SIGNAL(testSignal()),
            this, SLOT(onTestSignal()));

    forever {
        // ...
        myStateMachine->setState(StateMachine::S0);
    }
}

void MyThread::onTestSignal()
{
    qDebug() << "Test signal";
}

void MyThread::onNewState(StateMachine::state newState)
{
    qDebug() << "New state is:" << newState;
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

By using fully qualified names everywhere I got it to work

If I change the declaration of `stateChanged()` to

```
signals:
    void stateChanged(StateMachine::state newState);
```

And registers the type with

```
qRegisterMetaType<StateMachine::state>("StateMachine::state");
```

and also uses this name in the `connect` statement

```
connect(myStateMachine, SIGNAL(stateChanged(StateMachine::state)),
        this, SLOT(onNewState(StateMachine::state)));
```

Wouldn't have solved this without the input from drescherjm, thanks :-)

Comment: For the record, the reason why this solves the problem is that the metaobject system is deciding signal/slot compatibility based on (normalized) string comparisons.  It doesn't "know" that `StateMachine::state` and `state` refer to the same type in this context.

Comment: I've not needed qRegisterMetaType using Qt 4.8, just fully qualified names everywhere.

Comment: Got a similar example working without explicitly calling `qRegisterMetaType()` just by removing the semicolon from the line `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(StateMachine::state)`

Answer (score 5):

I believe the following is state is not defined in your MyThread class.

Use the following

```
 connect(myStateMachine, SIGNAL(stateChanged(StateMachine::state)),
            this, SLOT(onNewState(StateMachine::state)));
```

Edit:

Maybe this will work

```
 connect(myStateMachine, SIGNAL(stateChanged(state)),
            this, SLOT(onNewState(StateMachine::state)));
```

Comment: Then I get `No such signal StateMachine::stateChanged(StateMachine::state)` instead

Comment: Have you tried using a typedef in you MyThread interface. What I mean is typedef StateMachine::state state;

Comment: Always use full signatures in both signal/slot declarations (in the header) _and_ in the connect call.

Answer (score 0):

You should get rid of `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` since Qt can detect mismatches at compile time. You can also avoid having to use `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` and `qRegisterMetaType()` by using [Q_ENUM](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_ENUM) instead of `Q_ENUMS` - this was introduced in Qt 5.5, Finally `enum class` is a strongly typed version of `enum`:

```
// statemachine.h
#ifndef _STATEMACHINE_H
#define _STATEMACHINE_H

#include <QtCore>

class StateMachine : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_ENUM(state)

public:
    enum class state {S0, S1, S2};

    void setState(state newState);

signals:
    void stateChanged(state newState);
    void testSignal(void);
};

#endif

// main.cpp
#include <QtCore>
#include <QApplication>

#include "statemachine.h"
#include "main.h"

void MyThread::run()
{
    myStateMachine = new StateMachine();

    connect(myStateMachine, &StateMachine::stateChanged, this, &MyThread::NewState);

    connect(myStateMachine, &StateMachine::testSignal, this, &MyThread::onTestSignal);

    forever {
        // ...
        myStateMachine->setState(StateMachine::S0);
    }
}
```