# Qt enum in signal requires qRegisterMetaType

Tags: c++, qt, enums

I have an enum and a property in my `QObject`-based class like:

```
Q_ENUMS(StateEnum)
Q_PROPERTY(StateEnum state READ state NOTIFY stateChanged)
```

When I try to `emit stateChanged(state)`, I receive an error:

```
QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'StateEnum'
(Make sure 'StateEnum' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
```

Why do I need to invoke `qRegisterMetaType`? I thought that is what `Q_ENUMS` does.

Comment: are you using some ::connect s, or is this automatic from q_property itself? if you are doing some additional connects with usage of queued connection than you must use qRegisterMetaType.. but this is just shot in the dark.. have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368712/how-to-use-enums-in-qt-signals-and-slots)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the [`Q_ENUM()` macro](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_ENUM). This replaces the now-deprecated `Q_ENUMS` and will automatically register the metatype.

Your code should look like this:

```
Q_ENUM(StateEnum) //note the missing 'S' here
Q_PROPERTY(StateEnum state READ state NOTIFY stateChanged)
```