# How to pass enumerator type as a signal paramater in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have a header file where i have:

```
enum event {UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT, ACTION };
```

and I have Q_OBJECT class where I want to pass event type "events" as a signal paramater.

```
class GameView : public QGraphicsView {
            Q_OBJECT
            public:
                GameView(QWidget* parent, GameModel *m);
            ...
            signals:
                void sendEvent(event e);
            ...
};
```

But when I try to build it, the compiler says

> 'event' is not a type.

How can i pass the enumerator as a type correctly for the signal?

Comment: Is it the compiler? Is it moc? What's the *complete* error message?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use enums in Qt signals and slots](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368712/how-to-use-enums-in-qt-signals-and-slots). You're also missing the `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` macro (in the question). **Do your research next time.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a matter of signals or Qt. It is pure C++.

`event` is a member function of `QGraphicsView`. So when you write `void sendEvent(event e);`, `event` is not a type but a function.

You could write `void sendEvent(::event e);` which will force to resolve `event` at global scope.