# enums and enum classes in Qt Queued Slots

Tags: c++, qt, enums, enum-class

Following advice from [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_ENUM) and [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368712/how-to-use-enums-in-qt-signals-and-slots), I have code structured like so:

emulator.h:

```c++
class Emulator : public QObject
{
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        enum HaltCause {
            Breakpoint,
            ReadWatch,
            WriteWatch,
            UserHalted,
            Reset,
            SingleStep,
        };

        Q_ENUM(HaltCause)
    ...
    signals:
        void emulationHalted(HaltCause cause);
    ...
};
```

My MainWindow class has a matching slot:

```c++
    private slots:
        ...
        void onEmulationHalted(Emulator::HaltCause cause);
```

In mainwindow.cpp, the constructor contains:

```c++
...
    qRegisterMetaType<Emulator::HaltCause>();
...
```

and in a method invoked later on in the MainWindow class:

```c++
...
connect(m_emulator, &Emulator::emulationHalted, this, &MainWindow::onEmulationHalted);
...
```

The Emulator class is threaded, so the connection between its signal and MainWindow's slot is queued.

Regardless of seemingly following all the guidelines for getting something into Qt's meta-object system, I still get this debug message when the Emulator's thread `emit`s the signal:

```
QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'HaltCause'
(Make sure 'HaltCause' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
```

I've tried this with `Enumeration::HaltCause` being both a simple `enum` and a strongly-typed `enum class`.  Both yield the same results.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the unqualified `HaltCause` used in the declaration of `Emulator`'s slot confused the meta-object system.  The resolution was to change

```
signals:
    void EmulationHalted(HaltCause cause);
```

to

```
signals:
    void EmulationHalted(Emulator::HaltCause cause);
```

in the Emulator declaration (emulator.h).

Comment: Sounds like something you should report on bugreports.qt.io